# The sql string from queryset of django cannot be executed in pymysql?

Tags: python, django, pymysql

I'm using `Django` to make some param filtering, and then I got a filtered queryset like below:

```py
sql_str = str(my_queryset.query)
# print(sql_str)
```

```sql
SELECT `market_accounts`.`agency`, `market_accounts`.`id`, `market_accounts`.`entity`, `market_accounts`.`related_entity`
, `market_accounts`.`type`, `market_accounts`.`our_side_entity`, `market_accounts`.`short_title`, `market_accounts`.`titl
e`, `market_accounts`.`settlement_type`, `market_accounts`.`ae`, `market_accounts`.`sale`, `market_accounts`.`medium`, `m
arket_accounts`.`is_pc`, `market_accounts`.`is_new_customer` FROM `market_accounts` WHERE (`market_accounts`.`entity` LIK
E %madbaby% OR `market_accounts`.`related_entity` LIKE %madbaby% OR `market_accounts`.`short_title` LIKE %madbaby% OR
`market_accounts`.`title` LIKE %madbaby%) ORDER BY `market_accounts`.`id` DESC
```

And for some reason I want to execute the sql above by `pymysql`, but error showed like :

```
# cursor.execute(sql_str)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MyS
QL server version for the right syntax to use near '%madbaby% OR `market_accounts`.`related_entity` LIKE %madbaby% OR `
market_acco' at line 1")
Get Data Error!
```

Why the sql string generated by django cannot be executed by `pymysql`?

The sql I put above is what I got from `str(queryset.query)` directly. It missed `'  '` which confused me.

Comment: I think `%madbaby%` should be quoted `'%madbaby%'`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for replying, the sql above is what I get from queryset directly. It missed `'   '` which confusing me

Comment: Guys, he's not wrong. Django generates unquoted strings in str(qs.query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django generates unquoted strings in `str(qs.query)` so you shouldn't feed those to a database. These are for debugging purposes, though I agree it's a bit sloppy that they aren't properly quoted, it is mentioned in the source:

```py
    # django.db.models.sql.query.Query
    def __str__(self):
        """
        Return the query as a string of SQL with the parameter values
        substituted in (use sql_with_params() to see the unsubstituted string).

        Parameter values won't necessarily be quoted correctly, since that is
        done by the database interface at execution time.
        """
        sql, params = self.sql_with_params()
        return sql % params
```

Comment: Any suggestion for me to get the expected query sql?  Can I overwrite some method to make it?

Comment: In DEBUG mode `django.db.connection.queries` will have all properly formatted queries (which have been executed).

Answer (score 0):

LIKE pattern should be enclosed in quotes

```
LIKE '%madbaby'
```

In your query given

```
SELECT `market_accounts`.`agency`, `market_accounts`.`id`, `market_accounts`.`entity`, `market_accounts`.`related_entity`
, `market_accounts`.`type`, `market_accounts`.`our_side_entity`, `market_accounts`.`short_title`, `market_accounts`.`titl
e`, `market_accounts`.`settlement_type`, `market_accounts`.`ae`, `market_accounts`.`sale`, `market_accounts`.`medium`, `m
arket_accounts`.`is_pc`, `market_accounts`.`is_new_customer` FROM `market_accounts` WHERE (`market_accounts`.`entity` LIK
E %madbaby% OR `market_accounts`.`related_entity` LIKE %madbaby% OR `market_accounts`.`short_title` LIKE %madbaby% OR
`market_accounts`.`title` LIKE %madbaby%) ORDER BY `market_accounts`.`id` DESC
```

you clearly missed quotes for all the LIKE patterns

this should have been like this

```
SELECT `market_accounts`.`agency`, `market_accounts`.`id`, `market_accounts`.`entity`, `market_accounts`.`related_entity`
, `market_accounts`.`type`, `market_accounts`.`our_side_entity`, `market_accounts`.`short_title`, `market_accounts`.`titl
e`, `market_accounts`.`settlement_type`, `market_accounts`.`ae`, `market_accounts`.`sale`, `market_accounts`.`medium`, `m
arket_accounts`.`is_pc`, `market_accounts`.`is_new_customer` FROM `market_accounts` WHERE (`market_accounts`.`entity` LIK
E '%madbaby%' OR `market_accounts`.`related_entity` LIKE '%madbaby%' OR `market_accounts`.`short_title` LIKE '%madbaby%' OR
`market_accounts`.`title` LIKE '%madbaby%') ORDER BY `market_accounts`.`id` DESC
```

The error says that some error has been occurred just before

```
%madbaby% OR `market_accounts`.`related_entity` LIKE %madbaby% OR `
market_acco
```

which was caused by the missing quotes for the pattern.